# PXDBTimeSpanLong UI displays null values as zero

Tags: acumatica

When using the PXDBTimeSpanLong attribute, the UI displays null values as zero (00:00).

Is there anyway to change this behavior?  I would like null values to display as blank.

I want the users to know that the field has not been entered.  We have a validation that requires a non null value under certain circumstances and it's confusing that is shows 0 for null.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the external representation of the field with FieldSelecting event handler

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldSelecting<DACType, FieldType> e)
{
    e.ReturnValue = null;   //also try assigning an empty string
}
```